# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44386/odata/Customers'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, odata

I'm trying to retrieve all my data that is stored in my local database in a JSON format. I am currently following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtSsMkHmDpQ) to get my output. I have written the following code in my WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableQuerySupport();
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Team>("Teams");
        builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
        builder.EntitySet<Session>("Sessions");
        builder.EntitySet<SessionEventLog>("SessionEventLogs");
        builder.EntitySet<RequestCategory>("RequestCategories");
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
```

And I have 5 controller classes for each entity and they all contain this code:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    private readonly CX_DatabaseEntities db = new CX_DatabaseEntities();

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomer()
    {
        return db.Customers;
    }
}
```

In the video they use https://localhost:44386/odata/Customer to retrieve the data in JSON format but when I do it I get the following screen:

[image]

Comment: Don't use OData anymore. It is too complicated for a novice. Try to start from classical asp.net MVC and  you will have more luck.

Comment: @Serge Alright thanks for the advice. Will start with MVC web application

Comment: Pls don't take it personally I give this advise to anybody. OData was popular 10+ years ago. I don' t know anybody who uses it nowdays.